# How can I return the EOY (12/31/20**) historical stock share count over multiple years?

Tags: google-sheets

So I want to count how the management of several companies that I track are diluting existing shareholders. Is there a way that I can return the end-of-year share count over a timespan of 5-10 years?

I have used the formula: "=GOOGLEFINANCE("FB","shares", "12/31/2020")" to try to get the share count of Facebook (Meta) on December 31, 2020, but it returns "#N/A".

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Shared example would be helpful

Comment: Hi and welcome. Your formula doesn't work for two reasons. 1) the "ticker" must include the "exchange symbol" - this is "NASDAQ" for Facebook/Meta. 2) the "shares" attribute is only valid for "real-time data". FWIW, this returns the current number of shares: `=GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:FB","shares")` (= 2,366,278,000 shares). On a tangent, where "historical" data is available the interval is either "daily" or "weekly"; there is no "annual" option.

Answer (score 0):

*Is there a way that I can return the end-of-year share count over a timespan of 5-10 years?*

No. This isn't available from via the `GOOGLEFINANCE` function. The "shares" attribute (number of outstanding shares) is only valid for "real-time data", not for historical data.

FWIW, `GOOGLEFINANCE()` requires that the "ticker" should include the "exchange symbol" (this is "NASDAQ" for Facebook/Meta. So the formula to show the current number of shares is:
`=GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:FB","shares")` (= 2,366,278,000 shares).